# paste function for labeling in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following plot, I want to rename x-axis by `paste0` function.

```r
daata <- data.frame(
  q = paste0("q",1:20),
  value = runif(n = 20, 2, 10))

ggplot2::ggplot(data = daata, aes(x = q, y = value)) +
  geom_col()
```

so I used the following code:

```r
q = paste0("q",1:20)
labels <- paste0("'", q,"'" , " = ", 1:20) %>% noquote()
# Or
labels <- noquote(paste0("'", q,"'" , " = ", 1:20))

ggplot2::ggplot(data = daata, aes(x = q, y = value)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = labels)
```

[image]

### But it did not work. Why? (main question)

I want to search for solutions that make `labels = c("'q1' = 1", ...)` works.

#### Beside `paste` function I know two alternatives.

Using list:

```r
labels = sapply(1:20, list)
names(labels) <- daata$q
ggplot2::ggplot(data = daata, aes(x = q, y = value)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = labels)
```

Using function:

```r
ggplot2::ggplot(data = daata, aes(x = q, y = value)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(i){gsub("q", "", i)})
```

I am eager to know other solutions too.

Comment: If you read the documentation and examples at `?noquote` carefully, you will notice that the function's *only* purpose is for printing output at the console in a specific format, nothing else. You can think of it as merely attaching a flag, in the form of an S3 class, that causes a different `print` method to be called.

Comment: Stepping back, though, it is not clear to me from your question whether you want the labels to be formatted like `q = 5` or just `5`.

Comment: I already knew it because I have asked it before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026127/why-does-substitute-change-noquote-text-to-a-string-in-r
 So I just used `noquote` to show the failure and to search for a remedy

Comment: @joran I want just `5`

Comment: Ok, then in that case I'm just not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Why not use `ggplot2::ggplot(data = daata, aes(x = q, y = value)) + geom_col() +  scale_x_discrete(labels = 1:20)`?

Comment: I want to make the `paste` function works in this case.

Comment: @JonSpring `scale_x_discrete(labels = 1:20)` is dengourse in this case becuase it label `q10` with `2`

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? Extract the question number in the `data =` step, and use that for the axis:

```
daata <- data.frame(
  q = paste0("q",1:20),
  value = 1:20)

ggplot2::ggplot(data = daata %>% mutate(order = str_remove(q, "q") %>% as.numeric),
                aes(x = order,  y = value)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:20, minor_breaks = NULL)
```

[image]

Edit: here's an alternative that extracts the numeric part of the label. As you'll note, this preserves the alphabetical ordering created by mapping x to `q`.

```
ggplot2::ggplot(data = daata, aes(x = q, y = value)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) parse_number(x))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Jon. I want to search for solutions that make `labels = c("'q1' = 1", ...)` works.

Answer (score 0):

why not giving a named vector?

```
labels <- parse_number(as.character(daata$q))
names(labels) <- as.character(daata$q)

p1 <- ggplot2::ggplot(data = daata, aes(x = q, y = value)) +
  geom_col() 

p2 <- p1  + scale_x_discrete(labels = labels)
cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Jimbou, I want to search for solutions that make labels = c("'q1' = 1", ...) works.